# How to create swatch as simple product, which is created through configuration in Magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, products, magento2.2.6, simple-product, virtual-products

I have created a product of type simple. After that, I have created a swatch for the same product through the **"configuration" tab** on the same edit page.

When we create a swatch through the **"configuration" tab,** it creates a new product with visibility type **"Not Visible Individually"** and product type
**"virtual".**

I want when products created through **"configuration" tab** on the same edit page it should be the type of **"simple"**

Please check screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating configurable products using configurable tab.

Set weights of all associated products
[image]

If you don't add weight for each of your simple products, it will set it as virtual products

Comment: Sorry it's not working.... for me... "Apply unique quantity by attribute to each SKU".. it is still creating a virtual product.. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Updated my answer, tried it by myself. It's working now

Comment: Your way is correct .. but in Magento, it is required to add weight for the product, to avoid making them as the virtual product? Because I can see, the weight is not a required field in case of tangible/intangible product...

Comment: Simple product should have weight, all the other, like virtual and downloadable product would not contains weight. That's why when you create products with null value in weight it creates it with virtual type

Comment: Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: the issue is resolved and ans is voted up. But my concern is, what if, we forgot to add weight ... as weight is not required field...  or 

its a legal way for "Not to create the virtual product" through configuration tab?

Comment: or is there any programmatic way to by-pass this condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91282/discussion-between-shoaib-munir-and-rohan-katkar).